# prepareForSegue in Swift is changing the value of passAlongID and passAlongRow

Tags: ios, swift

I have attached my code below but I have a tableViewController and a normal ViewController which I call VideoViewController. I am trying to pass along the videoURL from my table to VideoViewController. Unfortunately it seems that my prepareForSegue function is changing the values of the passAlongID and passAlongRow. Could anyone help? I feel like this is an obvious issue that I am missing. Please let me know if you need any more information!

```
class VideoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
//var iphoneVideo: NSURL = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZwsbcW-d-E

var allYouTubeVideoURL = [NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wk5qT_814xM"), NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViuDsy7yb8M"), NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnf74-Bxtsg"), NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAVsBfOjc4c"), NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZwsbcW-d-E")]
var allYouTubeVideoNames = ["iPhone 6s - Timer - Behind The Scenes", "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - Teaser Trailer ", "DO TEENS KNOW 2000s MUSIC?", "The Real Saul Goodman from 'Breaking Bad' and 'Better Call Saul'?", "Suicide Squad – Blitz Trailer "]
var allYouTubeVideoImage = ["CookieMonster", "FantasticBeasts", "React", "SaulGoodman", "SuicideSquad"]

var passAlongID: NSURL?
var passAlongRow = 0

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.allYouTubeVideoImage.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "VideoCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    var videoURL = allYouTubeVideoURL[indexPath.row]
    passAlongID = videoURL
    passAlongRow = indexPath.row



    cell.videoName.text = allYouTubeVideoNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.videoPreviewImage.image = UIImage(named: allYouTubeVideoImage[indexPath.row])

    cell.playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VideoTableViewController.segueToVideoViewController), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func segueToVideoViewController() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showVideoSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showVideoSegue") {
            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
            let nextScene = segue.destinationViewController as! VideoViewController

                // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
                if let paid = passAlongID{
                    nextScene.newAllYouTubeVideoID = paid
                    nextScene.newPassAlongRow = passAlongRow
                }

            }
```

EDIT: I added all of the code for the VideoTableViewController

Comment: I don't see how the prepareForSegue method can know which cell was selected. You probably need to implement `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) `

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `passAlongRow` and `passAlongID ` .

Comment: @coopersita I use the play button for the segue though.

Comment: @ryantxr just added it.

Comment: Yes, but the `passAlongID` and `passAlongRow` don't change based on which one was clicked, but on the last cell to be loaded. You need to do the assignment when the button is clicked. At least, that's what I think.

Comment: @coopersita that worked! If you'd like to answer it formally I'll mark it as the best answer: All I had to do was add this: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var videoURL = allYouTubeVideoURL[indexPath.row]
        passAlongID = videoURL
        passAlongRow = indexPath.row
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showVideoSegue", sender: self)
    }

Comment: Nah... As long as it worked. Feel free to answer it yourself. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I **think** is happening.  If my assumption isn't correct, please add a comment.  `passAlongID` and `passAlongRow` are member variables. Function cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for every visible row. Assuming that 10 rows are visible, then these values are overwritten 10 times.  Their final value is whatever cell was last drawn. You need to link these to the playButton so that there is a different value for each cell.

One way to do this is to use playButton.tag and set it to the row number.

```
class VideoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    //var iphoneVideo: NSURL = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZwsbcW-d-E

    var allYouTubeVideoURL = [NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wk5qT_814xM"), NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViuDsy7yb8M"), NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnf74-Bxtsg"), NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAVsBfOjc4c"), NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZwsbcW-d-E")]
    var allYouTubeVideoNames = ["iPhone 6s - Timer - Behind The Scenes", "Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them - Teaser Trailer ", "DO TEENS KNOW 2000s MUSIC?", "The Real Saul Goodman from 'Breaking Bad' and 'Better Call Saul'?", "Suicide Squad – Blitz Trailer "]
    var allYouTubeVideoImage = ["CookieMonster", "FantasticBeasts", "React", "SaulGoodman", "SuicideSquad"]

    var passAlongID: NSURL?
    var passAlongRow = 0

    var selectedRow: Int = 0


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "VideoCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        var videoURL = allYouTubeVideoURL[indexPath.row]
        passAlongID = videoURL
        passAlongRow = indexPath.row

        // Tell the button which row it is associated to
        cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row

        // Assuming that this is a string. But if not, just change the type
        cell.playVideoURL = videoURL

        cell.videoName.text = allYouTubeVideoNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.videoPreviewImage.image = UIImage(named: allYouTubeVideoImage[indexPath.row])

        cell.playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VideoTableViewController.segueToVideoViewController), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    func segueToVideoViewController(sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showVideoSegue", sender: sender)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "showVideoSegue") {
            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
            let nextScene = segue.destinationViewController as! VideoViewController

            if let playButton = AnyObject as? UIButton {
                let row = playButton.tag
                if let paid = allYouTubeVideoURL[indexPath.row] {
                    nextScene.newAllYouTubeVideoID = paid
                    nextScene.newPassAlongRow = row
                }
            }

            // some missing code may go here?

        }
    }
```